# Multiple clickeble pdfs in a fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I know how to display one pdf file from my button.
I want to know how to display a list of pdfs and after that to open them.

### js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".fancypdf").click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
  type: 'html',
  autoSize: false,
  content: '<embed src="'+this.href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
  beforeClose: function() {
  $(".fancybox-inner").unwrap();
  }
  }); //fancybox
  return false;
  }); //click
</script>
```

### html

```
<div class="b-fisiere"> 
          <a class="fancypdf" rel="pdfuri" href="pdf/dental_dk50_dk50_10_MD.pdf">       
            <div class="b-fisiere-stanga">
            <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="b-fisiere-dreapta">FISIERE</div>     
          </div>
          </a>
```

New to this.
Thank you!

Comment: When you say "to display a list of pdfs" you are referring to a dropdownlist with the options or like a thumbnail?

Comment: yes that is what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the displaying of several pdf files, you need to use the select tag instead. For each option, I added a data-url attribute to put the url that points to the pdf to be diplayed.

```
<select id="pdfList" class="form-control">
  <option value="pdf1" data-url="https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf">#1</option>
  <option value="pdf2" data-url="http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D7000_ENnoprint.pdf">#2</option>
  <option value="pdf3" data-url="http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital.../manuals/pdf/index/x/fujifilm_xe1_manual_en.pdf">#3</option>
</select>
```

Last but not least, bind to the change event of the select tag. Remember the data-url I mentioned in the previous paragraph? Get the url from there.

```
$("#pdfList").change(function(e) {
  var $selectList = $(this),
    $selectedItem = $selectList.find(':selected');

  e.preventDefault();

  $.fancybox({
    type: 'html',
    autoSize: false,
    content: '<embed src="' + $selectedItem.data('url') + '#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
    beforeClose: function() {
      $(".fancybox-inner").unwrap();
    }
  }); //fancybox

}); //change
```

Please, refer to this plunker example to see it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/FTk556yDzdl9utncqhLa?p=preview